# Upload image to server from Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am trying to send an image to server. I converted the image to a byte array. I then tried the code from "[HTTP Post multipart file upload in Java ME](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HTTP_Post_multipart_file_upload_in_Java_ME)" on the Nokia developer forums.

I also tried the code from "[HTTP POST and passing parameters in URLs](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/181071-http-post-passing-parameters-urls.html)" on the BlackBerry forums.

I am passing parameters and  getting response code 200. But image is not sent to the server.  I am stuck on this.

Comment: It would be useful to include a small, relevant section of the code you are using.  Response code 200 is success, so the server was able to handle the request.

Answer (score 1):

```
try{

FileConnection fis=(FileConnection)Connector.open(filename);
InputStream inputStream = fis.openInputStream();

ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int buffersize=1024;
byte[] buffer=new byte[buffersize];
int length=0;
while((length=inputStream.read(buffer))!=-1)
{
    bos.write(buffer,0,length);
}
byte[] imagedata=bos.toByteArray();

HttpConnection conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(Url, Connector.READ_WRITE);
conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
conn.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE,                    
    HttpProtocolConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART_FORM_DATA
                        + ";boundary=" + boundary);

    conn.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH,
                String.valueOf(imagedata.length));
conn.setRequestProperty("x-rim-transcode-content", "none");

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStream finalOut = conn.openOutputStream();

String newLine = "\r\n";
out.write(newLine.getBytes());
out.write("--".getBytes());
out.write(boundary.getBytes());
out.write(newLine.getBytes());
String contDisp = "Content-Disposition:form-data;  
    name=\"file\";filename=\"Image.jpg\"";
String contEnc = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary";
String type = "Content-Type:image/jpeg";
out.write(contDisp.getBytes());
out.write(newLine.getBytes());
out.write(type.getBytes());
out.write(newLine.getBytes());
out.write(contEnc.getBytes());
out.write(newLine.getBytes());
out.write(newLine.getBytes());
out.write(imagedata);
out.write(newLine.getBytes());
out.write("--".getBytes());
out.write(boundary.getBytes());
out.write("--".getBytes());
out.write(newLine.getBytes());
finalOut.write(out.toByteArray());

out.flush();
out.close();

finalOut.flush();
finalOut.close();
InputStream instream=conn.openInputStream();
int ch=0;
StringBuffer buffesr=new StringBuffer();
while((ch=instream.read())!=-1)
{
    buffesr.append((char)ch);
}



catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Comment: Try this i have successfully pass image to the server with this code.

Comment: Hello Vijay, Thanks for your answer, but I am not able to understand that which URL we have to passed? can u give me the example for that? Thanks.

Comment: Your server address where you want to upload your image.

Example:
http://www.********.com/...............

Comment: at where you want to upload image give me your address i will set in this code.

Comment: This is the server path: http://74.208.77.106/jm/testing/FILENAME.jpeg. And what is boundry? Give me that string. Do I need to pass parameters in URL?

Comment: from where u get the image.
from device then first you get the image from the file and then pass the file to the Url.

Comment: Hey I tried. Now I am getting the response that 414 Request-URI Too Large. Image is created on server, but size is 0 KB. So no preview available.