# How to Upload an image in RIM Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I want to upload image in RIM Blakcberry. I have url like

```
http://server/myproject/json.php?action=image
```

and parameters

```
imageField= binary / byte data
imagePath= "userImage"
```

I refer [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793354/upload-image-to-server-from-blackberry)

But i unable to upload an image. Does anybody know?? Very much thankful..

Answer (score -1):

Refer to the ["Problem: How to upload file to server"](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Problem-How-to-upload-file-to-server/td-p/1865901) thread to know about uploading file over server.

Comment: Please ["Provide Context for Links"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) when answering a question on StackOverflow.